# Loop Will not terminate when passed innerHTML and (this.id)

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm writing a function that is supposed to replace a certain character at a certain location with a certain value with the given parameters. However, when I try to call the function inside of another. This is a homework assignment and I'm almost positive that I have the loop written correctly but feel as if I'm over looking something. *(this.id).charAt((this.id).length - 1) is supposed to get the last letter of the element's ID and pass it into the function. this.innerHTML is meant to take the contents of the HTML and pass it into the updateBoardState function*.

```
function updateBoardState(newMark, squareNumber)
{
    var boardState;
    var loc;
    var winners;

    winners = getWinningCombinations();
    boardState = getBoardState();

    loc = winners.indexOf(squareNumber);window.alert(loc);

    while(loc >= 0)
    {
        replaceCharacterInString(boardState, loc, newMark);
        loc = winners.indexOf(squareNumber);
    }
    setBoardState(boardState);window.alert(setBoardState(boardState));
}

function markTheSquare() // uses the this keyword to concatenate "X" to the inner HTML of the current element.
{

    this.onclick = null; // Disassociates the oncliick function with clicked()
    this.innerHTML = getXorO(); // Concatenates the result of getXorO to the current innherHTML of the element.

    updateBoardState(this.innerHTML, (this.id).charAt((this.id).length - 1));

    setMarkCount(getMarkCount() + 1) // Increment markCount by 1.


}
function replaceCharacterInString(source, where, what)
{
    return source.substring(0, where) + what + source.substring(where + 1, source.length);
}
```

Comment: what is replaceCharacterInString

Comment: It will just replace a character in a string. Example: replaceCharacterInString("Hello", 1, "x") should give back "Hxllo". source is the original string, where is the character number to be replace, and what is the character to be replaced.

Comment: I think the problem is you are replacing the contents of `loc`

Comment: he is never replacing "squareNumber", so loc will always be the same number?

Comment: The flowchart says "Search winners for the next occurrence of the square number and store the character number where the match begins in location." That is referencing to the inside of the while loop for the updateBoardState function.

Comment: will you be able to create a demo of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you are replacing something but that won't change the value of `loc` as the values used to find that remains same

Comment: one way to start is to log the value of the variables in the loop to see whether they reflects the expected values

Comment: so in the loop add `console.log(loc, winners)` as the last line

Comment: I have already written a solution @ArunPJohny. Thank you for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

My professor made a typo.

```
function updateBoardState(newMark, squareNumber)
{
    var boardState;
    var loc;
    var winners;

    winners = getWinningCombinations();
    boardState = getBoardState();

    loc = winners.indexOf(squareNumber);window.alert(loc);

    while(loc >= 0)
    {
        boardState = replaceCharacterInString(boardState, loc, newMark);
        loc = boardState.indexOf(squareNumber);
    }
    setBoardState(boardState);window.alert(setBoardState(boardState));
}
```